# Why compare time with moment.js fail?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I write a little function to check if the store is open or close. But the function don't work.

I try to change the hour but it the same result.

```js
   this.openTime.setHours(8);
    this.openTime.setMinutes(0); 
    this.closeTime.setHours(20);
    this.closeTime.setMinutes(30);


    var open = moment(this.openTime).format('H:mm');
    var close = moment(this.closeTime).format('H:mm');
    var now = moment(Date.now()).format('H:mm');
    console.log(close)
    console.log(now)
    if(now < close){
      console.log('open') // i have close in console !
    }else {
      console.log('close')
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: It took me few seconds to search. Why could not you?

Comment: sorry i don't find it

Comment: The link got broken in few minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.set()` of `moment.js`

The example .

```
    const day = moment('2017-08-01');
    day.set({ hours: 8, minutes:0 });

    const night = moment('2017-08-01');
    night.set({ hours: 20, minutes: 30 });

    var open = moment(day).format('H:mm');
    var close = moment(night).format('H:mm');
    var now = moment(Date.now()).format('H:mm');
    console.log(open)
    console.log(close)
    if(now < close){
      console.log('open') // You will have open in console !
    }else {
      console.log('close')
    }
```